How to charge a customer in stripe and get detailed information about Paymenta in PDF format
I have created product in stripe with price as $10.
I have a ui in the browser from which user can select no of products he want and can click on Pay Now button.
Suppose, a user selected 3 products. Then amount will be $30.
But, according to days remaining in the month we give discount to user using our algorithm.
How to charge a customer using stripe product Id by passing no of products i.e. quantity with PriceId.
But, total amount will also be provided by us.
How to charge customer using this conditions and generate detailed pdf about payment using stripe?
Is it possible to get detailed pdf?

You can create an invoice and  pass in your price and quantity accordingly. Then you can add a negative invoice line item to reduce the total amount due. Once you finalize the invoice you can find the PDF on the Invoice object.
